# How to extract repeated values from a database table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible extract the values of 'score' as shown below when multiple values of passageId are identical for each value of userId.

```
userId passageId score
1      1         2
1      2         3
1      1         4
1      1         5
2      1         3
2      3         3
2      3         4
```

Result:

```
userId passageId scores
1      1         2, 4, 5
1      2         3
2      1         3
2      3         3, 4
```

I was advised to use the following code, but I need more than two values to be extracted:

```
SELECT 
   userId,
   passageId,
   min(score) as score_1,
   max(score) as score_2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY    
   userId,
   passageId
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2;
```

I was also advised to use string_agg but could not make it work in pgAdmin.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgadmin suggests that you are using Postgres.  That in turn suggests that you should use `string_agg()` or `array_agg()`:

```
SELECT userId, passageId, ARRAY_AGG(score)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY userId, passageId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```